# Rails REST API Server: protect_from_forgery option and where to put authentication token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest

> **update (14/08/2015)**: Thanks to @EugZol's idea, I've updated the title, as the previous one is misleading.

I'm trying to build a Rails REST API server now.

I've read others' posts that I could use `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` to deal with the CSRF issue on JSON request, especially the POST request. I think this null_session will just clean the session(which is useless for JSON request).

But how could I do authentication on whether a user is logged in or not? I don't want to send password in every request. So I think maybe `:null_session` is not safe.

I'll be really appreciated if you could provide me some idea about:

1. How to do authentication checking for REST API server if it has `:null_session` specified?
2. If the solution is by using `authenticate_token`, where should I put this token in my JSON response? And where should the client put it?
3. Follow the previous one: Do I need to save a digest of that token in the database? I think the session will not be used now...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use cookies to authorize your client, CSRF can't be accomplished. It works only because browser would automatically add cookie to the request. E.g. when you open the following picture:

```
<img src="my.bank/withdraw_funds?to=john_doe">
```

you browser will make request to `my.bank` with cookies attached, authorizing the transfer.

But if you use some API token (as a request parameter or as a header), there is no way to make a malicious image/form that will add that token to the request (because the attacker doesn't know a token).

And, yes, you should put this token into the database. Rails' `session` use cookies, and API server, as mentioned, shouldn't rely on them.

You authentication method (probably somewhere in `ApplicationController`) would look like this:

```
before_action :authenticate

def authenticate
  @user = User.where(token: params.require(:token)).first
end
```

And then you can use `@user` in your actions. On the client side you just add `?token=...` to your request parameters.

If you use headers (and it's better, at least because you shouldn't worry about token being saved in proxy servers' logs when you do GET requests), you add `X-Authentication-Token: ...` header to your request, and then modify your `ApplicationController` like that:

```
before_action :authenticate

def authenticate
  @user = User.where(token: request.headers['HTTP_X_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN']).first
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That's really helpful! I think your explanation about **why we should put token in header** is really clear! Thanks again :)

Comment: Well, if you enforce SSL for every request (and it's good idea anyway), you probably could feel safe with token in request params. You are welcome! Consider upvoting my answer as well if you like it :)

Comment: Of course I will, but I'm under 15 reputation :-< BTW, do u think it's better to revise the topic of this question: The header is about protect_from_forgery function but we are talking about where to put token :) We may change it to **if :null_session, how to authenticate**

Comment: You can change it to something like "Rails as API Server: protect_from_forgery option and where to put authentication token", i.e. reflect both topics discussed.

Comment: Hi @EugZol, if you're available, could you please take a look at this [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011007/rest-api-server-login-authenticate-scenario) :)