# REST API server: login authenticate scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, authentication

Hi I'm building a authentication scenario of my Rails REST API server.

My plan is:

1. User send their *username* and *password* in the **authorization header** with **Base64** encryption.
2. Once it's authenticated by the server, the server will return a **auth_token** to the user, which could be used for authentication of this user.
3. If the user log out, that **auth_token** in the database will be destroyed.

Is this plan ok? What kind of problem will it have, in performance and security?

So many thanks!

> **update**: I'm using a mobile app to communicate with this server, and no session will be used.
>
> I think there's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051712/how-to-do-authentication-with-a-rest-api-right-browser-native-clients), which is quite huge and closed...

Comment: Assuming encrypted communication (HTTPS), a downside might be that every API call must explicitly provide the authentication token. One way of avoiding this, is storing the token in the session's cookie. It can still have a limited lifespan if you which, but your API calls wouldn't need to have it passed every time.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Зелёный. However, I think I need opinions. I need to know whether its good or bad for my future app.

Comment: i vote to close your question as off-topic.

Comment: Many thanks @AntwerpAtt, I've updated my question. I'll receive API call from mobile apps, which means no session will be used(with :null_session specified)

Comment: @VincentZhao Your plan sounds good to me. The only concern is the first step. If you use SSL, don't bother with additional encoding of your username and password (and you really should use SSL). If you don't, you should employ some [challenge-response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication) authentication mechanisms.

Comment: @EugZol So many thanks for your idea and suggestion :) That **challenge response** is a quite new concept to me, I'll try to understand it

Comment: @EugZol Just one more question... sorry to bother... Is Base64 encryption secure enough for the username+password in the request header?

Comment: @VincentZhao Nope, that was my point. Either SSL, or challenge/response techniques, no other secure options. Look at [CRAM-MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRAM-MD5) for example of the latter. But, really, set up SSL on your server, it's easy today with free certificates by WoSign and such.

Comment: Base64 is *not* encryption. It's a type of encoding. *Totally* different. Base 64 encoding is trivially 100% reversible.

Comment: "If you don't use SSL" isn't an option for APIs in 2015. SSL is minimum table stakes for authenticating any typical API now, and really all your traffic should be SSL, not just authentication. You certainly don't want to be passing the auth_token unencrypted.